# Trying to figure out how to check that the user entered 5-10 integers (java)

Tags: java

I'm trying to figure out how to allow the user to enter 5-10 integers, right now it only accepts 10 exactly.

I have tried adding that i also has to be greater than 5 but it does not work it crashes. If i set i less than 5 it takes 5 exactly and i need it to accept a range of 5 to 10 integer values
this is what i have:

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> getUserInput() {
    ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter 5-10 positive integers, on one line, separated by spaces: ");
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        arr.add(in.nextInt());
    }
    return arr;

}
```

Comment: Look at Scanner's `.hasNextInt()` method and a while loop, not a for loop.

Comment: ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter 5-10 positive integers, on one line, separated by spaces: ");
        //int i;
        String data = in.nextLine();
        Scanner s = new Scanner(data);
        int array[] = new int[10];
        int i = 0;
        while (s.hasNext()) { arr.add(in.nextInt());
        }
        return arr;

    } I have this now and it still doesnt work